# html5 fileapi binary data

Tags: html, gmail, filereader

Can you get the binary data from a file without the fileReader class? I'm trying to upload files and I have it working in firefox & chrome/webkit but safari 5 doesn't have filereader.

There has to be a way to get the binary data as gmail has drag and drop that works in safari 5.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, thanks to the demo here: http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2009/03/safari-4-multiple-upload-with-progress.html

I just need to feed the dataTransfer File...

```
var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("POST", "upload_process.php", true);

xhr.send(file); //passing in file object seems to work
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same problem but i am still not sure about the xhr.send(file). As while using the ASP.NET i got the error "Potentially dangerous data is detected ... ". I thought xhr.send(file) is not implemented by Safari considering FireReader itself is missing.

Its nice to know that xhr.send(file)  works in the Safari. I will try investigate it further.

However there is a better alternative for this which works great FormData.

```
var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "upload_process.php", true);
var fd= new FormData(); //its supported in the safari, chrome and firefox 4
fd.append(file.name, file);
xhr.send(fd); //passing in file object seems to work
```

There is one more issue i am facing right now, its [HTML5 DataTransfer detection error in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828183/html5-datatransfer-detection-error-in-chrome) please let me know in case you have faced and found any solution for this.